# Doctrine relation write NULL in table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, yaml, relationship

My Item.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item:
    type: entity
    manyToMany:
        categories:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            cascade: ['persist']
            inversedBy: items
            joinTable:
                name: item_category
                joinColumns:
                    item_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    category_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
    oneToMany:
        attributes:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue
            mappedBy: item
            cascade: ['persist','remove']
    table: items
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

AttrValue.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue:
    type: entity
    manyToOne:
        item:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Item
            inversedBy: attributes
            cascade: ['persist','remove']
            joinColumn:
                name: item_id
                referencedColumn: id
                nullable: false
        attribute:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Attribute
            inversedBy: attrValues
            cascade: ['persist','remove']
            joinColumn:
                name: attribute_id
                referencedColumn: id
                nullable: false
    table: attr_value
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AttrValueRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        value:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

Attribute.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Attribute:
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
            attrValues:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue
                mappedBy: attribute
                cascade: ['persist','remove']
    table: attribute
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AttributeRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        alias:
            type: string
            length: 255
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

When I want to send a POST request, in the form of a JSON array, everything seems to be written, but except for one field: item_id, NULL is written there. For deserialization I use JMSSerializer. What could be the problem? Entities getters and setters are standard.
JSON array:

```
{
    "name": "Book",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 11
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "value": "black",
            "attribute": {
                "alias": "color",
                "name": "color"
            }
        },
        {
            "value": "1",
            "attribute": {
                "alias": "price",
                "name": "price"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In MySQL table:

```
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
| id | item_id | value | attribute_id |
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
| 1 |    NULL | 6     |           8   |
| 2 |    NULL | black |           9   |
| 3 |    NULL | 6     |           10  |
| 4 |    NULL | bk    |           11  |
| 5 |    NULL | 1     |           12  |
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: Probably a copy/paste typo but you have your Item entity defined twice.  But the null problem simply means your setter is never called.  It's quite a common misconception.  Defining the relation for Doctrine does not mean that the setters are automatically called.

Comment: @Cerad, sorry, my wrong. But how I can call setter in this situation?

Comment: I can't tell really tell much from what you posted but typically in a bi-directional relation, the setter on one end needs to call the setter at the other end.  Do a bit of searching.  This question comes up many many times.